# Custom Home Icon in Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, drawable, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to set custom icon for home icon using [ActionBarSherlock library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). I have tried to set custom layout using `abHomeLayout` attribute in my custom theme. But it didn't work for me. Only way, how to set it, is to set `abIcon` attribute for my custom drawble, but I cannot set some horizontal padding for this drawable. Is there any example for this or where could be a problem with `abHomeLayout` attribute?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This works for my situation, it replaces the default ic_launcher icon in the action bar with my custom one.

In your onCreate do this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.audio_shortcut);
```

Or in the manifest you can set the logo:

```
<activity>
    android:logo="@drawable/my_custom_logo"
    ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

This works great too:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="icon">@drawable/my_custom_logo</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/my_custom_logo</item>
</style>
```

Reference: [How to change the ActionBar “Home” Icon to be something other than the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607271/842697)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with incorrect padding of the home icon on devices api<11 (i.e not the fully fledged platform action bar) and the `abHomeLayout` style only worked api>11

My solution was to copy the `abs__action_bar_home.xml` layout from ABS to child project and manually add padding to the `abs__home` imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/abs__home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/action_bar_home_icon_top_bottom_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/action_bar_home_icon_top_bottom_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/action_bar_home_icon_left_right_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/action_bar_home_icon_left_right_padding"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Comment: Was there anything else you needed to add to your style etc. to allow this to take effect?  I've copied the same file into res/layout/ of my project, but the tweaks to the padding don't seem to be working..

Comment: Bad answer, doesn't even say how to apply this layout

Answer (score -1):

Define an own style, like this:

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.OwnTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="abBackground">#476dd5</item>
    <item name="abHeight">30dip</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I think here your can use `abHomeLayout`.
Set this style for your activity like this:

```
<activity 
 android:name=".MainActivity" 
 android:theme="@style/Theme.OwnTheme">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In MainActivity you can use getSupportActionBar()... functions.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `abHomeLayout` as mentioned above. Without success, so I would need a working example.

Comment: This is an example of how to use ABS but doesn't answer the question at all