# Actionbar home icon in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am working off of the Styled project for ABS.  I would like to customize the home icon in the actionbar.  However, nothing I do seems to have any effect.  I have tried to set the logo in the Manifest, styles, and in MainActivity.  Has anybody come across this?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953807/custom-home-icon-in-action-bar-sherlock)

Apparently you must do `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_custom_drawable);` in MainActivity.  I get it, but it's cumbersome that it cannot be set in the Manifest...