# Action bar and changing icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using action bar in my app with sdk target 3.0. Is this possible to change icon from left side? This is default icon. I want to change this icon in every activity in code. In android 4.0 we have getActionBar().setIcon. But how I can do that in 3.0

Comment: check this below link, its suits for your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351479/android-how-to-change-the-actionbar-home-icon-to-be-something-other-than-the

Comment: ok, but how I can change icon from code in activity? This is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setLogo(Drawable logo);
```

Comment: in android api 11 I don't have this method

Comment: then u have to use higher api level

Comment: I can't. This is not depend on me. I must use api 11