# Change icon actionbar depending on the profile selected

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, profiles

I am trying to implement a ProfilesActivity in my app. So, imagine, we are in the home activity/layout: UsersActivity, where we have done addActions to init the actionbar like:

```
Intent addProfilesIntent = new Intent(this, ProfilesActivity.class);
    Action profilesAction = (Action) new IntentAction(this, addProfilesIntent,
            R.drawable.go_profiles);
    actionBar.addAction(profilesAction);
```

We click on profile's icon on our actionbar and it opens a new layout (profiles_menu.xml) where I have a listView with checkables items and an image for each profile (differents profiles: work, home, auxiliary...).

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();  
String []name={"    Company number","   Home number","   Handy number","   Auxiliary number"};  
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){  
    HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();  
    map.put("number_image", R.drawable.icon+(i+1));  
    map.put("number_name", name[i]);  
    listData.add(map);  
}  
listItemAdapter = new CheckboxAdapter(this, listData);
list.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);  
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Now, what I want to do is: when we select a profile it has to change the profile's icon on the action bar of the home page (this go_profiles in the code) into the selected profile icon. Do you know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: I am using this action bar https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

Comment: Want you to change the profile´s icon when you back to home activity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351479/android-how-to-change-the-actionbar-home-icon-to-be-something-other-than-the

Comment: But this link is about the home logo, it is not related to this case (I think, maybe I'm missing something) Thanks anyway