# Using a different icon in the Action Bar rather than using the default application icon

Tags: android

I have been working on bringing a new interface to my note taking application. I am wanting to design an icon that has depth to it and isn't as flat as the current one. However, when I upload an application icon that has depth to it, it looks so out of place in the colored action bar. I was wondering how I could go about using a different icon in the action bar than I would for the application icon, that way I could just use the flat pencil only within the action bar.

This is my current *styles.xml*:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ffd060</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
   <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I am using standard styling without any additional libraries (i.e Sherlock, ..etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the android:logo tag in your manifest like:

[Android: How to change the ActionBar "Home" Icon to be something other than the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351479/android-how-to-change-the-actionbar-home-icon-to-be-something-other-than-the)

For an individual activity in the activity tag of the manifest use:

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

Programmatically in your activity:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```