# Global header bar for Android project

Tags: android, xml

I am new to the Android and I am working on a partially completed Android project.

In all the screens of my app there is a header bar which has the logo of the app and the app name in the left. This header is automatically added to the newly created xml files too. But I want to remove the app icon from this header bar. When I look at my .xml file I don't find any reference to the logo or the app name. I suspect the header is defined globally somewhere in the project. How do I find that in my project so that I can edit it?

[image]

I want to remove the 'SD' image from the header. Here is my xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    tools:context=".AlbumFragment" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBook"
        android:name="com.hcpt.course.fragment.BookFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBookMark"
        android:name="com.hcpt.course.fragment.BookMarkFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSetting"
        android:name="com.hcpt.course.fragment.SettingFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentAbout"
        android:name="com.hcpt.course.fragment.AboutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check your `styles.xml` for `AppTheme`

Comment: @cricket_007 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />.  What should I do?

Comment: You are using Holo? What API level are you targetting?

Comment: @ cricket_007 minSdkVersion 13 targetSdkVersion 22. Is that a problem? I am sorry, I am completely new to this.

Comment: No, not a problem, just curious because new projects would use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to change the ActionBar "Home" Icon to be something other than the app icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351479/android-how-to-change-the-actionbar-home-icon-to-be-something-other-than-the)

Comment: Since my answer wasn't correct, that post discusses most of the details you need.