# Android icon in navigation bar

Tags: android, navigation, icons, drawer

How can I do something like this in android studio:

[image: Navigation bar with Title and Icon and Menue]

I would like to have a Navigation bar where you can see the name, the icon and also the oppurtinity to open a navigation drawer :D

(The picture was made in Figma)

Comment: you can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6351736/5255006

Answer (score 1):

set gravity to end in your NavigationView inside DrawerLayout.And add custom view to your toolbar.

```
<DrawerLayout ...>
  <Content>
  <Toolbar>
     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Here goes the Image -->
        <ImageView .../>  
        <!--Here goes the title -->
        <TextView ...
           android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </Toolbar>
   <MainContent .../>
  </Content>
  <NavigationView 
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    .../>
</DrawerLayout>
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you! But what to start with? Create a new Navigation Drawer acitivity?

Comment: you could start with that.